# How can i remove the button bar on an Embedded PageViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a container view object with layout constraints set to the entire screen (0, 0, 0, 0). The container view embeds a UIPageViewController. When I build the app and run it on an iPhoneX, there is a white bar cutting of the bottom of each view in the UIPageViewController. Is there anyway to make this full screen and get rid of the button white bar completely?

[image: Storyboard setup]

[image: Issue]

Comment: Does bottom anchor pinned to bottom safeArea guide?

Answer (score 0):

That is the home indicator. Try using [prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden)

```
override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```